# Store oracle row value on php variable

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle with this columns: IMGPOSX, IMGPOSY and IDIMG. Each row of the table has a different X Y value positions and an ID to identify witch of this values correspond to an specified ID.

For example: `IDIMG = image1 > IMGPOSX = 20 IMGPOSY = 50`

With this value then I build a html map image and load the image with an specified ID and put the results of the IMGPOSX and IMGPOSY on the margin-top and margin-left css properties.

I have found several example of how to get the values of the first line of the row but i don't know how to get the another ones (the table has 12 rows)

With the next code I get the first row of each column (IMGPOSX, IMGPOSY and IDIMG) but i don't know how to get the rest of the rows of the table. If I put row1[1] the parser get an error.

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('TEST', 'TEST', 'ORCL');
if (!$conn) {
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT IMGPOSX, IMGPOSY, IDIMG FROM TESTTABLE ');

if(oci_execute($stid))

{
$row=oci_fetch_row($stid) ;

"<table border='2'>";

print"<tr><td><p>posx: </td><td>$row[0] </td></tr>";
print"<tr><td>posy: </td><td>$row[1] </td></tr>";
print"<tr><td>idimg: </td><td>$row[2] </td></tr>";

print"</table></br>";   

}

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

Also I like to filter the results of the fetch by the idimg, for example, some code that says "showme only the IMGPOSX and IMGPOSY from the `IDIMG='image2'`.

Answer (score 0):

A rough example could be appending a WHERE clause to your query:

```
$id = 'image2';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT IMGPOSX, IMGPOSY, IDIMG FROM TESTTABLE WHERE IMDIMG = $id;");
```

or, with the same query, you can filter with IF:

```
if ($row[2] == $id) {
//show
}
```

The sentence before your code states that you could need more than one row, so if you are not filtering, you will recieve more, to get them you need a proper fetch. Your current one if fetch_row, maybe you need fetch_array in order to recieve array with all values.

I would suggest `oci_fetch_assoc` http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-assoc.php so you can access the column via their names. Also the filtering will use a named column.

```
if ($row['IDIMG'] == $id) {
//show
}
```

Have in mind the following sentence of the function description:
`This function is typically called in a loop until it returns FALSE`

You'd need something like:

```
<?php
//all the code here
// ...
// ...
?>
    <table border="2">
<?php while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)): ?>
    <tr><td><p>posx:</p></td><td><?=$row['IMGPOSX'];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><p>posy:</p></td><td><?=$row['IMGPOSY'];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><p>idimg:</p></td><td><?=$row['IDIMG'];?></td></tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    </table><br />
<?php
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```